# How to disable a QPushButton

Tags: python, button, pyqt4

I tried calling UI from another file, but couldn't disable a button. I don't know where to place `.setEnabled(False)`. I placed it everywhere except `main`, but the button is still enabled.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from a import Ui_MainWindow

class machine(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(machine, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()
        self.disablebtn()
        self.btn_Save.setEnabled(False);
        self.btn_Close.setEnabled(False);  
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.desktopSize()
        self.statusbar().showMessage("super dooper")
        self.btn_Save.setEnabled(False);
        self.btn_Close.setEnabled(False);  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does your `Ui_MainWindow` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your `machine` class **does** disable the buttons correctly, but you never create an instance of it, and so it never gets a chance to work properly.

The code should probably look more like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from a import Ui_MainWindow

class machine(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(machine, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("super dooper")
        self.btn_Save.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_Close.setEnabled(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = machine()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: or `def setupUi(self, self): super(...).setupUi(self); ...`

Comment: @warvariuc. Sorry, but I have no idea what that code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: I mean you have two methods `initUI` and `setupUi` with similar names and responsibilities. So I suggested to put the additional code into  `setupUi` calling the parent implementation too. Sorry for confusion with `def setupUi(self, self)`

Comment: @warvariuc. But they don't have similar responsibilities. A method like `initUI` *resets* the properties of existing widgets, and could be called multiple times. But `setupUi` *constructs* the widgets (and their layouts), and is only intended to be called once.

Comment: ah, ok. Can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966200/casting-a-qobject-subclass-instance)?