# Casting a QObject subclass instance

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a `QPixmap` subclass with additional class method `make`:

```
class Screenshot(QtGui.QPixmap):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls):
        desktop_widget = QtGui.QApplication.desktop()
        image = cls.grabWindow(
            desktop_widget.winId(), rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), rect.height())
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() 
        image.save()
        return image
```

When I call `Screenshot.make()` the correct class `cls` is passed, but the instance created via `cls.grabWindow` is not a `Screenshot`:

```
ipdb> ...py(30)make()
     29         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 30         image.save()
     31         return image

ipdb> cls
<class 'viewshow.screenshot.Screenshot'>
ipdb> image
<PyQt4.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x7f0f8c4a9668>
```

Even shorter:

```
ipdb> Screenshot.grabWindow(desktop_widget.winId())
<PyQt4.QtGui.QPixmap object at 0x7f0f8154c438>
```

How to get a `Screenshot` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods `Screenshot` inherits from `QPixmap` will return a `QPixmap`, so you need to explicitly create and return an instance of `Screenshot` instead.

The only real issue is to avoid inefficient copying. However, `QPixmap` provides a very fast copy-constructor for doing just that, so all you need is something like this:

```
class Screenshot(QtGui.QPixmap):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls):
        ...
        image = cls.grabWindow(...)
        return cls(image)
```

Comment: Looks good, but doesn't work: after `image = cls(image)` `image.size()` is empty. Could a bug in PyQt. For now `image.__class__ = cls` works.

Comment: Oh, `image = cls(image)` calls my `__init__`, not the overloaded from C++.

Comment: @warvariuc. My answer works perfectly fine. Your `__init__` function (which is not shown in your question) is obviously broken, probably because it doesn't call the base-class `__init__` properly.

Comment: My `__init__` handles only the case when a parent widget is passed. It also has additional argument for my needs. I think I'll have to use `*args, **kwargs`. Still, it's a pity that `cls.grabWindow(...)` doesn't return in instance of `cls`. Is this documented somewhere? Does PySide do the same?